# Login using google account and showing purchased movie from playstore

Tags: php, api, gmail

I am very new to Google API implementation. Need help regarding this.
My Requirement -
Showing purchased movie from play store in a single web page (php page) using google account
I have client id, secret key etc.
Let me know how to do it.
Firstly I need to login using gmail id. Then to show movie from it.
I have downloaded a google-auth-api from github. the example are not working properly

Comment: Was the project you downloaded this one, or something else? https://github.com/tcw3bb/google-auth-api

Comment: I downloaded the google-auth-api from github last day, which contains few examples.
I placed the client Id, secret key there but it was not working.

At least I need login using google account, so that after providing few required credential to google, I will test what exact return data from google

Comment: I downloaded the agoogle api php client from https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Answer (score 0):

The Google Play Store does not appear to expose any API to determine what movies a user has purchased. The only purchases APIs I was able to find were specific to Android, and only work on in-app purchases for the current application.

Comment: Then can we not access the user's services using and providing proper credential to google auth php client?

Comment: I found that , the purchased video is being listed under youtube "purchases" link. I have search everyday but did not get any proper code or proper ans on this.

Now I want to get all the purchased video in a single webpage.
I tried with the video id, it works but its a static one, if infuture use buy other video we can not get id dynamically.